# Why does spidermonkey give me a segmentation fault when i call the clear() function?

Tags: shell, segmentation-fault, spidermonkey

A little help. I just built spidermonkey on debian (./configure, make, make install) and when i run the js shell and call the clear() function, I get a segmentation fault. Any idea why this may be or where I may get help? Has this happened to anyone?

> $js
>   clear() ;
>   Segmentation fault
>   $

Comment: You do realize that clear(); clears everything? most likey something gets GC'd that the JS Shell needs to function properly. This is the default behavior. The same error reproduces on my linux console.

Comment: It might be easier for a knowledgable soul to help you specifically if you could post the output of version(); Mine reports 185.

Comment: I see now.. this happens because you called clear on the global object. If this were called in some properly written code using a sandbox or something like that, this wouldn't happen. The sandbox would be destroyed, not the global object.

Answer (score 0):

Calling clear in the JS Shell with no arguments deletes the global object. In an interactive session, the read-eval-print loop will try to access the global object that has previously been destroyed. End result: segmentation fault. Moreover, the global object no longer exists.

Comment: Ok so this is default behavior? There might be a reason for this to be default behavior but I don't really see it. One would think the behavior would be a little more sophisticated than "Segmentation fault" but it's good to be aware of it however.

Comment: I agree. But the way the code is written in the shell (this is a spidermonkey shell function) If you don't supply an object it defaults to the main object of the caller. This is especially useful to for cleaning up sandboxes. There should be some code in there to check that you aren't going to GC the global object, but then you couldn't clean out your sandbox using clear();

Comment: This could be avoided with a refrence check however. You might want to suggest it as a bug for the SpiderMonkey Shell.